# Code echoing a \n somehow

Tags: php

I am using the following code to share my sessions between PHP and Node.JS.

http://pastie.org/4874088

What the problem is, is that as I have to include it at the beginning of every script, I get a weird problem:

Basically somewhere along that code there is **something** that **is echoing a new line**, breaking some AJAX functions that I use (sharing small text bits between client and server).

I am having a hard time finding this ugly line; can you find it?

It is important to note that the line must be exactly in this file and not in

```
require("$appDirectory/vars/lib/Predis/Autoloader.php");
```

as I tried removing the predis client, too.

Thanks in advance.

Screenshot: [imgur.com/RSpyA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgroh.jpg) : line 1 is the problem:

[image]

Comment: what is the error are you getting

Comment: http://imgur.com/RSpyA that there is a new line before anything echoed by me

Comment: than please show your code ...with these information its difficult to trace your problem

Comment: my code is irrelevant. even if my code would be empty, just by requiring the php pasted here ( http://pastie.org/4874088 ), it would echo that new line you see there.

Comment: Perhaps a new line after `?>` somewhere

Comment: RC you are right.... could never think of this one! thank you! also because pastie totally removed the new lines from the file. post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @johnsmith glad I did help. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a new line after `?>` somewhere

Comment: That's why "?>" shall be avided and never used if file is pure php script

Comment: Didn't know about that, webnet! You say I can remove the ?> from all my scripts?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `Autoloader.php`.Try to find out in this file.May be you are using like this

```
 <?php echo "something"; ?>
              //or

<?php //somevalues

?>

<?php
// see the new lines b/w two php blocks
?>
```

Comment: it's not that. I tried removing it from the file and I still got the same problem, as described in the question. It was the fact that there is a new line between the PHPs but, RC answered before you, sorry about that...